# Number of simple edge-disjoint paths needed to cover a planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $|E|=m$ of a graph class $\mathcal{G}$. A *path-cover* $\mathcal{P}=\{P_1,\ldots,P_k\}$ is a **partition** of $E$ into edge-disjoint simple paths. The size of the cover is $\sigma(\mathcal{P})=k$. I am interested in upper and lower bounds for the quantity

$$ \max_{G\in \mathcal{G}} \quad  \min_{\mathcal{P} \text{ is path-cover of $G$}} \sigma(\mathcal{P})/m.$$

In other words, how large is the inverse of the average path length in the smallest path-cover in the worst case.

The graphs classes $\mathcal{G}$ I am interested in are (1) planar 3-connected graphs, and (2) triangulations.

There is a simple observation for a lower bound: In every odd-degree vertex one path has to start/end. So when all vertices have odd degree there any path-cover needs at least  $m/6+1$ paths (a triangulation has $3|V|-6$ edges). You get the same result by noticing, that $(n-1)/2$ paths have to pass through a vertex of degree $n-1$.

Is a path-cover with $\frac{m}{6}$ paths always possible for planar graphs?

I am aware of a few [results](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X04000603) covering planar graphs with paths of length $3$.

Here is an example of a path-cover of the graph of the icosahedron.

[image]

Comment: This is a great question; don't know why it hasn't received more attention or upvotes.

Comment: I don't understand the lower bound.  Since a triangulation has $m=3n-6$ edges, a triangulation with all odd-degree vertices requires at least $n/2=(m+6)/6=m/6+1$ paths.  For instance, $K_4$ needs $2$ (not $1$) paths to cover it.

Comment: I am not sure if I would be able to do it, but somebody should try generating a big list of $\sigma(\mathcal{P})$'s for a bunch of the graphs in question.  Maybe some data will help us see a pattern.

Comment: @A.Schulz Maybe the lower bound $m/6$ is weak for some classes of graphs. For instance, for the wheel graphs $W_n$, consisting of the cycle of length $n-1$ and the additional center vertex joined with all vertices of the cycle. Also there are Moon-Moser graphs $T_k$ (see Section 2 of the article “[Long Cycles in 3-Connected Graphs](http://webfile.ru/6536808)” by Guantao Chen and Xingxing Yu), having no cycles of length greater than $(7/2) n^{\log_3 2}$. Maybe these graphs also have no small path-covers.

Comment: A related question is that of Linear Arboricity, but the results for it are based upon the maximum degree of vertices. See for instance http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~kowalik/papers/LinearArboricity.pdf

Comment: Note that $\sigma(\mathcal{P})/m$ is not the average path length, but its inverse.

Comment: Have you tried to look at a necklace of squares in which each square (4-cycle) is connected to its 2 neighbors by edges going out from 2 opposite vertices?

Comment: For $m$ isolated edges you need $m$ paths...

Comment: Isn't the icosahedron graph at least an example where $m/6$ paths is not enough? This has $m=30$ but requires at least $6$ paths.

Comment: @EinarRødland: I oversimplified and made an estimation with $3|V|$ edges instead of $3|V|-6$ edges. If you use the later bound you get $m/6 + 1$ paths (as for the icosahedron or tetrahedron). Still my main question is, whether the degree constraint is the only constraint for a path cover.

Comment: @A.Schulz: OK, that resolves that case. In order to be true for the regular triangle, it is required that the simple path be allowed to be a cycle: these seems to be some variation in how _simple path_ is defined.

Answer (score 7):

I will show that $\frac{m}{6}$ is not enough for 3-connected planar graphs. The following is inspired by fedja's comment (and also some nice discussion with Krystal Guo).

Consider the [prism graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrismGraph.html), which we will denote $P_n$. We say it has $2n$ vertices and $3n$ edges. Then in this case $\frac{m}{6} = \frac{n}{2}$. We will show that $\sigma(P_n) =n $. It is clear that $n$ paths is enough.

Consider the following graphs which we denote $T_n$:
[image: $T_n$]

and so on.. Note that $T_n$ has $3n - 1$ edges and $2n+2$ vertices.

It is not too hard to show that $\sigma(T_n) = n+1$ (and this is the best possible). One can show by induction, considering the left most edge between the upper and lower paths.

Let $p_1 , \ldots , p_k$ be a path cover of $P_n$. Now $P_n$ is two copies of $C_n$ with a matching, $M$, in between them. If every $e \in M$ is actually some $p_i$, then we have $k \geq n+2$.

So we may assume there is a $e = (u,v)$ such that the path, $p_i$, that contains $e$, contains at least one more edge, wolog say $(v,w)$.

$(i)$ The vertex $u$ is also contained in another edge of $p_i$ (other than $e$). Then $(V(P_n) , E(P_n) \setminus E(p_i))$ is $T_n$ minus at most two paths (actually, exactly two: the two paths start with precisely the two edges incident to $e$, respectively). In this case $k \geq n+1 - 2 + 1 = n$ (the last $+1$: don't forget to count $p_i$).

$(ii)$ The vertex $u$ is not contained in any other edge of $p_i$. Then let $p_j$ be another path that contains $u$. Then $(V(P_n) , E(P_n) \setminus (E(p_i)\cup E(p_j))$ is a $T_n$ minus at most 3 paths ($p_i$ is one path in $T_n$ and $p_j$ is at most two paths in $T_n$). It follows that $k \geq n + 1 - 3 +2= n$.

Thus we obtain $\sigma(P_n) = n$, as desired.